# Can i programmatically play radio on android?

Tags: android, android-source

I have on my s2 a predefined app that lets me listen to radio. It doesn't use the Internet, instead it uses the surrounding radio waves. Is there any way in which i can use that feature to  programmatically start the radio and search for radio stations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can't, according to [this post in the Android googlegroup](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d692479c86e6eb8c?pli=1).

I guess that the most you can do is **launching** the radio app via an appropriate intent; I think, however, that these intents belong to a single vendor's SDK (check this [presentation from Archos, for instance](http://www.archos.com/support/download/software/ArchosAPIdemo.pdf) ).

So, I think that your best bet is to search for similar, **vendor-provided** api by Samsung

Answer (score 2):

There is no API in the AOSP for FM radio. Thus, you cannot build your application with radio support. At the same time, SE proposed their solution for radio support but it is still not included in the main branch. You can read about it
[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/eFhxfsxqIMc).

At the same time, in some custom roms you already can find examples how to play with radio. For instance, [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_FM) is the code of application that is included in the Cyanogenmod. You can build and install this application on your phone and see if it works. If it is then you can build your application basing on this approach.

Also check the answer from the previous message.